# Eclipse CheckStyle Marker

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle, marker

I think this is a question for eclipse experts. Where is the checkstyle marker location? I am using a plug in that is calculating warnings that apper in project and and  it shows me zero checkstyle warnings , while there are around 300 !!! Looking at the plug in configuartions i see that is looking for markers : com.atlassw.tools.eclipse.checkstyle.CheckstyleMarker

i have no idea !!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean Eclipse -> Window -> Show View -> Other -> Checkstyle : ?

Comment: What do you mean by location? I use Checkstyle in my daily work, and provide a special configuration for others in our project, so I know checkstyle a little bit. I thought Checkstyle in Eclipse is just using the problems of Eclipse, so the infrastructure of eclipse should be the "location"

Answer (score 1):

Well, Eclipse (3.6) stores the checkstyle findings in a file called `.markers` in the `.metadata` directory of the workspace:

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\MyProject\.markers
```

That's a binary file though, so I don't think reading it will do you any good. It is one way to check that certain markers exist, though. (Quite possibly not the best.)

Normally, the `Problems` view of Eclipse shows you all markers: *Window -> Show View -> Problems*. Entries with type `Checkstyle problem` are generated by Checkstyle. Check the `Resource` and `Path` columns in that view in order to make sure you are comparing findings in the right scope.

You can clear the Checkstyle markers from a project by right-clicking it and selecting *Checkstyle -> Clear Checkstyle violations* from the context menu. They are recreated when the project is built. (Provided the checkstyle builder is active, which you can check in the project properties under *Builders*).